# C# post request stuck in WaitingForActivation even with timeout

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a simple post request using HttpClient (which as far as I can tell is the current correct way to handle post requests.) However, the code is stalling on timeoutTask.Result, with the tasks stuck on Status=WaitingForActivation.  Looking at the server side of things, I can tell that the post request is being sent and data is being returned, and I have also called wget manually and verified that some text data is correctly returned from the server for this post request.

This happened when I simply called task.Result, so I tried to add a timeout task, but I must be making some mistake with async because it still hangs on timeoutTask.Result.

```
class HttpPostExample
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public void processSentence()
        {
            string uri = "http://localhost:9000/?properties={%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%22%2C%22outputFormat%22%3A%22json%22}";
            string result = postSync(uri, "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static async Task<string> postAsync(string uri, string postData)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(postData);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseContent;
        }

        public static async Task<string> runTaskWithTimeout(Task<string> task, double seconds)
        {
            if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds))) == task)
            {
                // task completed within timeout
                return task.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                // timeout logic
                return "timed out";
            }
        }

        public static string postSync(string uri, string postData)
        {
            var task = postAsync(uri, postData);
            var timeoutTask = runTaskWithTimeout(task, 2.0);
            return timeoutTask.Result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling an `async` method from a synchronous method you may want to try and add `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all of your await lines. Generally it is good idea to use `async` all the way or add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocks.

Check out this blog post for an example: https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f